# Setting multiple maps points

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I hope all is well!

I'm new to android, and is on a project that I need to take multiple longitude and latitude outputs from address using Geocoder, and put those points on the map.

This is my Map Fragment that shows the map and a point at Sydney:

```
class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)

        var mapFragment: SupportMapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback {
            onMapReady(it)
        })

        return view
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        var mMap = googleMap

        mMap!! .mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID

        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```

If I have multiple items on a recycler view to collect the longitude and latitude, is there a built-in function to save the longitude and latitude pair and display them on the map?

Thanks!

Comment: You just want to create a list of lat longs, iterate through them, each time calling mMap.addMarker()

Comment: @RichardDapice thank you. I'm getting the lat and longs from another fragment A using geocoder (converting from address to lat and longs). Should I find a way to call this addMarker() in this fragment A?

Comment: No, you need to consider a method in which to hold presentation data that it can be accessed from this map fragment. Utilizing a pattern like this in the app will alleviate alot of your headaches in the future.

Comment: You do not necessarily need to focus on passing the data, more on storing at retrieving.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/architecture-patterns-in-android-abf99f2b6f70

Comment: @RichardDapice Thank you! Actually I was required to do this project in MVVM (and retrofit). I watched and read a lot of examples and guides on the MVVM. I understand the concept, but I don't know how to convert all that into code. I couldn't find a step-by-step tutorial. Most tutorials posted a chunk of code that a few lines of explanation, without really explaning why and what we put in the classes specifically. I'm a slow learner so it was tough. That's why i'm doing it this way -- putting all the code into the fragment (view)

Comment: You could always create an object in kotlin. It will be a singleton, you can store things there. It won't scale well but it might get you started.

Check out these code labs on your journey.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=Android

Comment: @RichardDapice I actually created a singleton to store it! Thank you for coming back!

Comment: Your welcome, good luck with your project.